# MySQL Syntax for finding differences

Tags: mysql

I have two tables with varying columns. But some columns are the same.
Let's say `first_name`, `last_name`, `email` are the same withing these 2 tables.

- `table 1` is full.
- `table 2` is being filled by a form, so it will always be less than or equal to the rows of `table 1`.

I need help writing a query that would allow me to check `table 2` against `table 1` and return all the missing `first_name`, `last_name`, `email` from `table 1` that are NOT YET in `table 2`.

Comment: I've tried JOINS but they return data that is in both. How can i limit the return only to the missing data.

Comment: please give your table definitions.

Comment: Why are table definitions necessary. I only care for the 3 columns listed? Table1(field1, first_name, last_name, email, field2, field3) table2(first_name, last_name, email).

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this request could work, you could give it a try :

```
SELECT first_name, last_name, email 
FROM table1 t1
LEFT JOIN table2 t2 ON t1.email = t2.email
WHERE t2.email IS NULL;
```

Comment: This query hangs for a really long time.